# How can i make winding and unwinding the rope / cable animation

Tags: animation

Making a rower machine. And i want to make the cable / coil to spin or rotate inside it. Any idea how to make the cable / coil reel. I have made the curve and trying to make spool. I have parented the handle and cable. When the handle is move in X axis or stretch the coil winding up. When release the handle the coil unwinding up. Any suggestion how it works. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/animating-wire-cable-rope-wrapping-around-a-cylinder  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder

Comment: In order not to duplicate, (this Q may be considered such,) I've posted a new answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215044/35559), alongside one of @Chris' suggestions.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes i think i want that way. Thanks