# How I can wrap the rope around cylinder?

Tags: modeling

I want to wrap this rope, based on curve around cylinder:[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/animating-wire-cable-rope-wrapping-around-a-cylinder

Comment: It seems what you need is to measure the radius of a cylinder you want to wrap around (the wood beam), and the radius of the wrapper (the rope), sum it together and that's the radius of a circle you want to form with your curve. Then just scale that circle along X axis and duplicate it a few times.