# How to wrap the rope around the drum

Tags: animation

[image]

You have to wind the wire rope on the left at number 1 and then wind it again at number 2, is there a way to draw a curve and follow it?

Comment: have you tried with a Curve modifier for your rope? (also please avoid "help me" and "I'm going crazy")

Comment: sorry, i'm don't speak english, so i missed here's rule.
i never do that words

Comment: There is a tutorial for rigging a drawbridge [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw0UcHhcAk4). Unfortunately the instructor is explaining the technique in English with a heavy French accent which you might find difficult to understand.

Comment: Another tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEWu88Ymydw).

Comment: The drawbridge toot fails to fix the chain to the spool (the coil slides along it) Check out one of the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183182/35559)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder

Answer (score 2):

add cylinder

R X 90

[image]

make sure your add-on is enabled

[image]

Shift A -> Curve -> Curve Spirals -> Archimedian

[image]

change settings like this:

[image]

[image]

Tab -> edit mode

[image]

select this vertex

[image]

E Z 8

[image]

Tab

Shift A -> Mesh -> Cylinder

[image]

Tab -> CTRL R

[image]

Tab

select Curve

CTRL A -> Location

select cylinder, add modifier:

[image]

enter 50 in z location, keyframe location on frame 1

[image]

enter 30 in z location , keyframe location at frame 50

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here I go, supplementing one of your answers again. I hope you don't mind. I'd written mine, when yours turned up and did the job. :)

Comment: thank you!! of course i don't mind

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes to add to @Chris's [very comprehensive answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252675/35559).

- If this is a friction drive, the animation of the cable is simple. It's just a translation of the cable along its deformation axis, down a **static** curve, by which it is deformed.
- The curve can be constructed to existing spools, by <kbd>E</kbd> extruding the ends of a Curve Spirals > Archimedean curve, taking the thickness of the cable into account:

[image]

- The distance the rope has to be translated per revolution of the large spool with a spiral diameter of `D` is strictly `sqrt((D*pi)^2 + h^2)`, where `h` is the height per wind of the spiral. But if `h` is small, `D*pi` will probably do.
- The rate at which the small spool with diameter `d` must rotate is `D/d` times the rate at which the large spool rotates.

**If you need the animation to loop...**

There are some added constraints, if you don't want miles of rope.

- The pattern on the rope must match at the beginning and end of the temporal loop. In the example below, the loop is at a 180⁰ turn of the large spool. Perhaps the easiest way to achieve the match is to make the cable an *array* of elements, each one of which has a length of `D*pi` (or, strictly, again, the expression above) and ensure a match between the ends of the elements, successfully merged by the *Array* modifier.
- So there is no jump in the animation of the small spool, its visible features must loop at the same time as those of the large spool. Most simply, `d` can divide `D` by a whole number.

[image]