# How can I make a parametric winch (or a roll of rope)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this so far:

[image]

But how can I make it grow increasingly, like a winch would do?

I tried 'Snap' math function everywhere but it doesn't really do much good.

Nodes:
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the layer number (index / points_per_layer) to the radius, multiplied by a thickness factor, to offset the rope with each additional layer. Use the snap or truncate node to get a constant offset for each point in the layer, until it snaps to the next.

The Switch node in the modified file below toggles between the simple Truncate behavior (sharp jump between layers) and a smoothed version i made to get a more natural transition between layers. There's a test mesh to play around with this function.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Whoa! Works like magic :) Thank you so much, incredible. It wasn't that easy a problem after all, I see

Answer (score 2):

The final parametric .blend based on @lukas_t 's answer:

[image]

[image]