# Easy way to animate a bale wrapper

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

What's an easy way to animate a bale wrapper like in the GIF below?

[image]

https://giphy.com/gifs/machine-hay-bale-5ThN9qBDfD97i

Comment: i edited your question to "an easy" instead of "best" because else the question will be closed because it is opinioned based....hope that's ok for you

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw the warning when I posted it but didn't know how enforced it is. Oops...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnLVVbVQnvE) recent tutorial will be of use to you.

Comment: Well I kind of did it, by keying gravity to basically force the cloth to wrap around. Now I'd need to figure out how to 'pull' the end of the cloth around and un-spool it from a roll of cloth.

Comment: Close to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder/76788#76788