How to animate stretching or wrapping fabric around an object?

Hello everyone,
I have a stretch machine. I want to make this machine from the animation in the link I gave. But I couldn't find any source. Can you help me? What steps should I follow? Or is there a resource you can recommend?
Example link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kWtLVw2xTo&ab_channel=OrionPackaging

Thank you very much for your reply. This should roughly clear some things up. But I can't fix the bevel on the edges. In addition, it will be very difficult to ensure that this coating material comes from a single source with hooks.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder/76766#76766

Create a bezier curve, press V > Vector, extrude and put it all around your pack, in the Data panel choose Twist Method > Z-Up, extrude it, and animate its Start & End Mapping > Factor Start so that it extends:

Select each vertex in Edit mode and press CtrlH > Hook to New Object so that the vertex is controlled by an empty (here just 2 hooks but do it for all the vertices of the curve):

Animate the empties this way:


This should roughly clear some things up. But I can't fix the bevel on the edges. In addition, it will be very difficult to ensure that this coating material comes from a single source with hooks. Screenshoot
